# Wordpress: List categories and list all posts in active category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hoping that I can get some assistance on this one! I'm trying to implement some PHP in the sidebar that displays a list of the categories (as links to the category itself). If clicked, I'd like it to go to the category page of course, and then for the posts within that category to appear in a list underneath it as links.

Example of the homepage:
Category A
Category B
Category C

Example of the homepage within Category A:
Category A
  - Post One
  - Post Two
  - Post Three
Category B
Category C

I'm sorry if this is something obvious. I'm trying to find my own solution but thus far have been unable to.

Thanks again!

Comment: The `wp_list_categories()` function ought to take care of the first half of your question. Reference here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: Hey there. :-) Yeah, I got that part down but the difficulty is trying to get a list of posts for only the current category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this codes for displaying the categories and the list of posts in 
hierarchial order:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives with Content
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="widecolumn">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div class="post">
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
<div class="entrytext">
<?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
</div>
<div id="main">
<?php //include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>
<h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
<ul>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=daily&limit=1&show_post_count=1'); ?>

</ul>
<h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
<ul>

<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=1'); ?>
</ul>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

1.Just copy the above codes in a file named archieve_page.php.then,go to admin->pages->add page and give title as archieve page and in the right side corner,click the dropdown template and select the "Archieve with content" and click publish and in the top click "view page" to see the page.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little widget that does include something like that the code might get you started to create your widget: http://wp.leau.co/2010/12/01/sidebar-feed-widget-showing-tweets-stumbles-vids-and-more/

Just loop the categories as above

Then with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category you can check if you are on a category page, then check with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title if it is the active page